# Copy array (passed as a function argument) elements into another local array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code:

```
(function (window) {
  function javJavScript() {
    var _javJavObject = {};
    var elemImg = [];

    _javJavObject.myCustomLog = function (thingToLog) {
      console.log("My-Custom-Log > Type of variable : " + typeof (thingToLog));
      console.log("My-Custom-Log > Is number : " + !isNaN(thingToLog));
      console.log("My-Custom-Log > Length : " + (thingToLog).length);

      return console.log(thingToLog);
    };

    _javJavObject.imageArrayRandomizer = function (elementID, elemImg) {
      var imgArray = [];
      var i = imgArray.length;
      var cloneElemImg = elemImg.slice(0);
      for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        imgArray[i] = elemImg[i];
      }
      document.write(imgArray[0]);
      document.write("<br>" + elemImg[0]);
      var elemBG = document.getElementById(elementID);
      if (i) {
        elemBG.style.background = imgArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * i)];
      }
    };



    return _javJavObject;
  }


  if (typeof (window.javJavScript) === 'undefined') { window.javJavScript = javJavScript(); }
})(window);



javJavScript.imageArrayRandomizer('my-body', ["blue", "red", "green", "yellow"]);
```

I call the `imageArrayRandomizer` function and see that `imgArray[0]` is `undefined` while `elemImg[0]` is "blue" (as it should be). I've read other questions about my issue here - they recommend using the apply() or splice() method but I'm probably not using those properly, because I can't get the result I want. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++)
```

Well `imgArray` is empty so the for loop wont run. May do:

```
for (i = 0; i < elemImg.length; i++)
```

Comment: Geez,thanks,such a small thing but it fixes everything ! :)